# Getting error "The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to fix it but it didn't work for me. I think I am missing something, it works in older version of Flutter but not in recent one.

I am trying to set (onTap) function on an image to go to the next widget screen.

Here is my code:

```dart
    import 'dart:js';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:zar/screen/category.dart';
    
    class TopCard extends StatefulWidget {
      const TopCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<TopCard> createState() => _TopCardState();
    }
    
    // TOP CARD CLASS STARTS HERE
    class CardItem {
      final String urlImage;
      final String title;
      final String subTitle;
    
      const CardItem({
        required this.urlImage,
        required this.title,
        required this.subTitle,
      });
    }
    
    // TOP CARD WIDGETS STARTS HERE
    Widget topCard({
      required CardItem item,
    }) =>
        Container(
          width: 150,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 2 / 2,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: Material(
                      child: Ink.image(
                        image: NetworkImage(item.urlImage),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Categories(
                                item: item,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 4),
              Text(
                item.title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                item.subTitle,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
    
    class _TopCardState extends State<TopCard> {
    // TOP CARD LIST VIEW STARTS HERE
      List<CardItem> items = const [
        CardItem(
          urlImage:
              'https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/pizza-melted-cartoon-illustration-flat-cartoon-style_138676-2876.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg',
          title: 'PIZZA',
          subTitle: '\$20',
        ),
        CardItem(
          urlImage:
              'https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/triangle-sandwich-cartoon-icon-illustration_368721-11.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg',
          title: 'SANDWICH',
          subTitle: '\$7.99',
        ),
        CardItem(
          urlImage:
              'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/french-fries-icon-flat-vector-related-icon-long-shadow-web-mobile-applications-can-be-used-as-logo-pictogram-icon-90676285.jpg',
          title: 'FRIES',
          subTitle: '\$2.99',
        ),
        CardItem(
          urlImage:
              'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/42/de/53/42de53a97cac79ddcaee570c436a10e6.jpg',
          title: 'BURGER',
          subTitle: '\$5.99',
        ),
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          height: 150,
          child: ListView.separated(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 4,
            separatorBuilder: (constext, _) => const SizedBox(width: 16),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => topCard(
              item: items[index],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

But I get Error in (context)

```
    child: InkWell(
     onTap: () => Navigator.push(
     context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => Categories(
        item: item,
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your helper method needs the `context`

```
 child: InkWell(
     onTap: () => Navigator.push(
     context, // HERE You need context
      MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => Categories(
        item: item,
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
```

So add it as a parameter

// TOP CARD WIDGETS STARTS HERE

```
Widget topCard({
      required CardItem item,
      required BuildContext context
    }) => ...
```

and remove

```
import 'dart:js'; // it gives you another context that you don't need 'JsObject'
```

Another solution is to move `topCard` helper method within your state class, so you dont have to pass the `context` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. Flutter automatically imported dart.js library, which is giving the error. Go to the top of the file and remove this line:

```
import 'dart:js';
```